# Booth bit-pair recoding of multipliers

Tags: arithmetic, multiplication

1) In Booth's bit-pair recording technique how to multiply a multiplicand with 2?

2) In booth's algorithm for multiplication/Booth's bit-pair recording of multipliers, the sign bit extension of the multiplicand i.e. we must extend the sign-bit value of the multiplicand to the left as far as the product will extend. Now my question is what should be the value of extended Sign Bit?

I think following are the possible values-

Multiplier  Bit, Extended sign bit value

i)      0,                                               0

ii)       +1,                                               0

iii)      -1,                                               1

iv)       -2,                                               1

v)         2,                                            I don't know

Also, why is the sign bit extended? Will we get the correct answer if we  don't extend sign bit?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51435290/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W didn't you noticed that nobody is giving any answer to my question at any site.